Can't see 2D cursor when drawing grease pencil
Good day. Is it possible to see the 2D cursor when you draw a fill with a grease pencil? I've looked in the settings and can't find anything related to the 2D cursor in grease pencil drawing mode. The "Display Cursor" option does not help.

While you're in draw mode if you look at the top bar, there should be a little symbol that looks like a pair of black and white circles next to a squiggle icon. Thats the viewport overlays panel, in there near the top you should see a check box for "3D Cursor".

Thank you, @Jakemoyo. It was helpful! But this is about a 3D cursor. Do you know if it is possible to increase the pencil cursor when I draw in Grease Pencil in the Drawing Mode? The cursor is so small that I draw blindly!
